# How to Delete data from firebase using Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic 3 to get data from firebase in form of chats/messages with these functions

```
getChats(userTwoId: string) {
   return this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser()
  .map(auth => auth.uid)
  .mergeMap(uid => this.database.list(`/user-messages/${uid}/${userTwoId}`))
  .mergeMap(chats => {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      chats.map(chat => 
this.database.object(`/messages/${chat.$key}`).first()),
      ( ...vals: Message[]) => {
        // console.log(vals);
        return vals;
      }
    )
  })
 }

getLastMessagesForUser(): Observable<Message[]> {
   return this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser()
   .map(auth => auth.uid)
   .mergeMap(authId => this.database.list(`/last-messages/${authId}`))
   .mergeMap(messageIds => {
   return Observable.forkJoin(
    messageIds.map(message => {
      return this.database.object(`/messages/${message.key}`)
        .first()
    }),
    (...values) => {
      return values;
    }
  )
})
}
```

How do i delete these chats and lastmessages using a function?
can someone help me please

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the key from the firebase object in question, generally this is the `.$key` value, once you have that you can use the `.remove()` functionality assuming you are using ionic 3 w/ angularfire2

For example:

```
this.db.object('messages/' + chatKey).remove();
```

In this example we assume that in my firebase my node is messages and it has a child, the key is `chatKey`. You would need to define `chatKey` before hand or replace *`chatKey`* with your own variable for the `.$key`